# What is difference between intersection over union (IoU) and intersection over bounding box (IoBB)?

Tags: image-classification, image-recognition, object-detection

Can someone give a detailed explanation IoU and IoBB along with that the differences between them.

Comment: Can you give a reference that uses "intersection over bounding box"? Googling the exact term returns no result.

Comment: [The two answers here have nice explanations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28723670/3126298). There isn't a big difference between the two. We are strictly talking about bounding boxes in the latter, but it uses the same principle.

Comment: For reference, you can see the following paper:                                              
title={Chestx-ray8: Hospital-scale chest x-ray database and benchmarks on weakly-supervised classification and localization of common thorax diseases},
  author={Wang, Xiaosong and Peng, Yifan and Lu, Le and Lu, Zhiyong and Bagheri, Mohammadhadi and Summers, Ronald M},
  booktitle={Computer Vision and Pattern Recognition (CVPR), 2017 IEEE Conference on},
  pages={3462--3471},
  year={2017},
  organization={IEEE}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Intersection over Bounding Box is the Intersection over Union (IoU) for object detection tasks, where you have a bounding box.

There are many tasks (e.g. image segmentation) where you have an IoU (the predicted segment vs the actual segment), but there are no bounding boxes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about IoBB (Intersection over detected B-Box) used in medical imaging, I think it is different from IoU. IoBB would divide overlapped area over the area of detected B-Box not the Union of it.

In medical imaging, sometimes the detector identified smaller parts of a large or scattered lesion with a big ground-truth bounding-box so IoBB is used.

Actually I am also looking for a strict definition of IoBB since when I calculated the IoU from my result, it was quite different from the reference result where used IoBB instead of IoU..